# Finding a preset value nearest to the column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation

For those who run into this question twice; apologies. I'm trying to obtain the same answer using different code; I also posted this for obtaining M, powerquery or excel solutions.

I need to retrieve the nearest matching value in a fixed set values for an entire column.

The set of values that have to be matched looks as follows

```
| preceding column | Sys_size | 
===============================
| ...              |     null |
| ...              |        7 |
| ...              |        9 |
| ...              |       12 |
| ...              |       15 |
| ...              |       17 |
| ...              |     null |
```

so in short, the list above is variable (more sizes could be added or changed), and contains null values.

Second there's a bunch of variable numbers as follows

```
| preceding column | User_size |
================================
| ...              |       8.5 |
| ...              |        13 |
| ...              |         6 |
| ...              |      10.5 |
| ...              |        18 |
| ...              |        14 |
```

The result I want to obtain in my script looks like this

```
| preceding column | User_size | Sys_size |
===========================================
| ...              |       8.5 |        9 |
| ...              |        13 |       12 |
| ...              |         6 |        7 |
| ...              |      10.5 |       12 |
| ...              |        18 |       17 |
| ...              |        14 |       15 |
```

simply put, it searches the nearest `Sys_size` matching the `User_size` input. Note that in case the user's value falls exactly between two `Sys_size` values the result is rounded up.

So far I have achieved the inverted version of this which looks something along the lines of this, but only works with fixed value input:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sys_Size
FROM System
WHERE ABS(Sys_Size - 8.5) = (
  SELECT MIN(ABS(Sys_Size - 8.5))
  FROM System
)
```

which would return `9`

But this has to be systematically applied to the entire user column. I feel I'm ridiculously close and overlooking something very obvious.

Comment: Where User_Size is 13, Sys_Size is 12, is this a mistake?  Same with 18 -> 17.

Comment: @MJH no this is the intention. Matching the nearest sys_size value. 13 is closer to 12 than 15. Same with 18; 17 is the largest sys_size value hence anything above 17 is closest to 17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `apply`:

```
select u.*, s.sys_size
from users u cross apply
     (select top (1) u.*
      from system s
      where s.sys_size is not null
      order by abs(s.sys_size - u.user_size)
     ) s;
```

Answer (score 1):

two options the I know of

```
declare @U table (s decimal(5,2));
declare @S table (s decimal(5,2));
insert into @U values (7), (9), (12), (15), (17); 
insert into @S values (8.5), (13), (6), (10.5), (18), (14); 

select u.s, ss.s 
from @U u
cross apply ( select top 1 s.s 
              from @S s 
              order by abs(u.s - s.s)
            ) ss;

select us, ss, diff 
from 
( select u.s as us, s.s as ss 
       , abs(s.s - u.s) as diff 
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by u.s order by abs(s.s - u.s) asc) as rn
  from @U u
  cross join @S s 
  where u.s is not null and s.s is not null 
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
order by us, rn
```